# Neo4j How to find a node connected somehow to another given node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

in a database I have different distinct disconnected graphs. Each graph has a root node (r:Root {name:""}) which have different name properties (Root label + name property is a unique identifier). The only thing I know of these graphs is that a copy of a node with a given label (e.g :node1) can exist in each graphs. Given the root node (r:Root {name:"XYZ"}) and the target label (e.g. :node1) how can I find the node connected to the root that has name=XYZ without knowing how it is connected?

I tried

```
Match (n:node1)-[r*0..]-(:Root {name:"XYZ"}) return n
```

but the query is stucked. I don't know the number and the type of relationships between node1 and the root.

EDIT:
[image]

The problem is shown above. Inside the circles there are the node labels (i omitted the other labels). Inside the cloud I have the parameters. My wish is to return the node :node1 connected to the root named "pippo". The only thing I know are the labels Root, node1 (that is not unique) and the root's name (that is unique). I cannot assume anything about the way :node1 is connected to the root node.

Comment: That can be a very expensive query. Do you have other properties of the two copies that you know will be in common? You might be able to use that to narrow down your search.

Comment: No, i just know the label of the node i want to return and the label+property of the root. I just simply need a query to find a node connected to another without knowing how many relationships there are between the two and without knowing the kind of relationships

Comment: You have to get rid of the `r` in the relationship part, because it's conflicting with the `r` in the second node match; you also might want to assign a variable to the path, like this: `match path=((n:node1)-[*]-(r:Root{name:"XYZ"})) return n` just in case you want to know how many hops it is from `n` to `r`.

Comment: see the comment on your answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you're nearly there, but you need to limit the path length. Try this:

```
match path=((n:node1)-[*0..15]-(:Root{name:"XYZ"})) return n
```

You don't need to name the `:Root` node, since you're not returning anything about it. And you need to get rid of naming the relationship, since it conflicts with the variable name you gave the `:Root`, though perhaps that is moot if you leave that out.

Comment: Sorry, the r:Root was my mistake, I don't have it in my code. I don't have any property inside node1. The node is empty yet. I am trying to find in order to add them using `SET n.attribute1='..'`

Comment: That's a very confusing comment, to the point that I don't know what you're trying to do anymore. What I have here will find any node with the `node` label and the name `XYZ`, connected by any number of hops to a node with the `Root` label and the name `XYZ`. This is what I thought you mean when you wrote, "Given the root node (r:Root {name:"XYZ"}) and the target label (e.g. :node1) how can I find the node connected to the root that has name=XYZ without knowing how it is connected?" If you want something different, then write something different.

Comment: What do you mean 'the node is empty"? Do you mean it doesn't exist at all? Or it does exist but doesn't have any properties? Or something else?

Comment: It exists but it doesn't have any property. name=XYZ is referred to the root node. Sorry for my not so good english capability

Comment: Well, if the node you're trying to find doesn't have the same name, then you're asking the impossible. You can't find two nodes with the same name, if you know in advance one of them doesn't have that name defined. What are you really trying to find?

Comment: Think about it this way: what is the unique characteristic of the node you're trying to find? If you were looking at your graph manually, and you found one of these root nodes, and then you went about trying to find one of these target nodes, how would you know you had found it?

Comment: I am not trying to find two nodes that have the same name. I am trying to find a node of which I know just the label that is connected to a node of which I know the label and a property (in this case name).

Comment: All right, in that case what I've got now should do the trick.

Comment: The query I have written should work. How many nodes and relationships do you have in your database? Also, do you want the query to return the number and type of relationships in-between the root and the node1?

Comment: No, I just want to return the node node1. I tryied with your query and it remains stucked. I have 52 nodes and 66 relationships. The first query I tried that made me open this question was `match (n:node1)-[r*0..]-(:Root {name:"xyz"}) return n` and has the same behaviour of yours

Comment: Try a few diagnostic queries like this: `match(r:Root{name:"XYZ"}) return r` and `match(n:node1) return n` and make sure they return stuff. And then, since your database is so small, just do `match (n) return n` and look at everything.

Comment: They all works fine. `match(r:Root{name:"XYZ"}) return r` returns the root node. `match(n:node1) return n` returns all the nodes with label node1 and  `match (n) return n` returns all the graphs.

Comment: When you do that last one, can you visually find root nodes, and see if any of them are connected to `node1` nodes?

Comment: sure, they're connected through a chain of nodes and requirements

Comment: What's the maximum number of hops any of the roots are from the `node1` nodes? Because one thing you can do to greatly increase performance on queries like this is to provide an upper bound on the number of hops.

Comment: nowadays is more or less 4-5 hops. But i cannot expect anything sure. Yeah almost not more than 15 I guess

Comment: I tried using `match (n:node1)-[*0..15]-(:Root{name:"XYZ"}) return n` and it works! I think you're right and give an upper bound helps! Thank you!